# Dart: cannot assigna type with generics to a Type variable

Tags: generics, types, dart

If I try to assign a type with generics to a Type variable I get an error, but if I use a runtimeType variable everything works fine.

```
  Type t = List;
  //Type t1 = List<int>;  // ERROR !!!
  Type t2 = new List<int>().runtimeType;
  print('$t $t2');  //> List List<int>
```

Is it a bug or there is something I'm not getting?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52891829/7616528) worked great for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line is surprising, but, yes, it works. Class literals have type "Type":

```
print((List).runtimeType);
--> TypeImpl

print(List is Type);
--> true
```

The problem with the rest of your snippet is exactly the issue you found on github:

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/11923

-- that class literals cannot use generics. You'll have to get an instance and use runtimeType to get the type you want here.

Answer (score -1):

`Type` is not a class you can make be any other class. It is the type of the `runtimeType` property of objects. It is used for reasoning about what type an object is.

```
Type t = List;
```

Dos not magically make the type of `t` a `List`;

```
Type t = List<int>;
```

This tries to assign a `List<int>` to a variable of type `Type`, hence the error.

Perhaps some confusion stems from:

```
print(t);
```

Which prints `List`, but this is really printing `t.toString()` which returns the String 'List'.

Comment: So, why 
`Type t = List<int>;`
cannot hold the type `List<int>`
while
`Type t2 = new List<int>().runtimeType;`
can?

Comment: runtimeType is an object of type Type.  Where as new List<int> is an object of type List<int>.  Obviously confusing, but that is why.

Comment: I think you are mixing up the concepts of Type and class. An object of type  `Type` _is not class_. It's the type of the runtimeType property of any object, and it pretty much just holds the String name of the runtimeType.

Comment: Humm, so, `List` is a Type, right? `List<int>` is a type with generics. Why I can assign to a variable of type Type `List` but not `List<int>`?
The variable of type Type can hold a `List<int>`, because if I set it through the runtimeType of a class everything works fine.

Comment: Well, no, it's a class. What's confusing you I think is that there is another class called Type (https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.23.0/dart-core/Type-class.html) that is for holding information about classes at runtime. I don't know why `Type t = List;` works but `Type t = List<int>;` does not. Usually a Type is obtained from the `runtimeType` property of an object.

Comment: I'm exactly talking about the class Type. Looking at the documentaion `List` is called a class literal. But, if I understood correctly, every class in Dart is an instance of type Type.
So I hope to have clarified the terminology.

Comment: I have found the following bug still open on git: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/11923

Comment: Where have you read that every class in Dart is an instance of type Type?

Comment: I have found in a discussion on the web, but probably is more correct the sentence "every class in Dart is an instance of a metaclass of type Type".