# How to get generic Type?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to obtain the `Type` of a generic class. Ideally I'd like the following:

```
Type type = MyClass<int>;
```

But this is throws a syntax error. 
What is the proper way to get access this type information?

I know that I can get this type using `runtimeType` like so:

```
final foo = MyClass<int>();
Type type = foo.runtimeType;
```

But this requires an instance of the object; which doesn't fit my use-case.

Comment: It's for flutter

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**Edit: as of Dart 2.15 this trick is not needed anymore**

See Dart 2.15 announcement: https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-2-15-7e7a598e508a

```dart
var z = List<int>; // New in 2.15.
var z = typeOf<List<int>>(); // Pre-2.15 workaround.
```

---

Old answer:

Dart doesn't support type arguments in class literals (https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/11923)

But you can write a small generic helper:

```dart
Type typeOf<T>() => T;

main() {
  Type type = typeOf<MyClass<int>>();
  print(type);
}
```

Comment: Is there a library that does this? Or is there a dart api that does this? Seems like it should be part of dart by now

Comment: You can abbreviate this if you need it just once to: `(<T>() => T)<T>()`

Answer (score 1):

```
extension Typing<T> on List<T> {
  Type get genericType => T;
}

T? data;
Type type = <T>[].genericType;
```