# Why can't I use generic Type as an argument in Dart 2?

Tags: dart

This seems to be allowed

```
  List<Type> myTypes = List();
  myTypes.add(SomeType);

  List<Type> moreTypes = [int, String];
```

but this fails?

```
  List<Type> myTypes = List();
  myTypes.add(SomeGenericType<int>);

  List<Type> moreTypes = [SomeGenericType<int>, SomeGenericType<String>];
```

The error message is:

The operator '<' isn't defined for the class 'Type'.
Try defining the operator '<'.

I'm new to Dart coming mainly from a C,C# background, so this seems confusing and inconsistent. Why is a generic type treated any differently than a non-generic?

Comment: Even this is not allowed: Type myType = SomeGenericType<int>;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This relates to this question: [How to get generic Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52891537/how-to-get-generic-type) - but it isn't a real duplicate question, that's why I replicate it here.

While it doesn't answer the "Why", it gives the solution for the "How":

Helper function:

```
Type typeOf<T>() => T;
```

And then you can get the type without a needed instance:

```
myTypes.add(typeOf<SomeGenericType<int>>());
```